# Is Windows Media Player dead? JS has no access to 'Controls'?

Tags: javascript, windows-media-player

So... The company I work for has long used a javascript wrapper to control the position of a video being played back.

Historically, this has been achieved by using something to this effect:

```
function loadMovie(movieIndex, moviePosition)
{
    if ( top.mediaFrame.document.MediaPlayer.URL != movieArray[movieIndex])
    {
        top.mediaFrame.document.MediaPlayer.URL = movieArray[movieIndex];
    }
    top.mediaFrame.document.MediaPlayer.controls.currentPosition = moviePosition;
    top.mediaFrame.document.MediaPlayer.controls.play();
    return false;
}

// I've tried .controls.currentPosition And .Controls.currentPosition to no avail.
```

Where the 'MediaPlayer' object is something like this:

```
<OBJECT id="MediaPlayer" width="440" height="360" CLASSID="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6" type="application/x-oleobject">
    <param name="URL" value="/images/logo.png">
    <param name="rate" value="1">
    <param name="balance" value="0">
    <param name="currentPosition" value="0">
    <param name="defaultFrame" value>
    <param name="playCount" value="1">
    <param name="autoStart" value="-1">
    <param name="currentMarker" value="0">
    <param name="invokeURLs" value="-1">
    <param name="baseURL" value>
    <param name="volume" value="50">
    <param name="mute" value="0">
    <param name="uiMode" value="full">
    <param name="stretchToFit" value="0">
    <param name="windowlessVideo" value="0">
    <param name="enabled" value="-1">
    <param name="enableContextMenu" value="-1">
    <param name="fullScreen" value="0">
    <param name="SAMIStyle" value>
    <param name="SAMILang" value>
    <param name="SAMIFilename" value>
    <param name="captioningID" value>
    <param name="enableErrorDialogs" value="0">
    <param name="_cx" value="10451">
    <param name="_cy" value="10583">
    <embed TYPE="application/x-mplayer2" SRC="/images/logo.png" NAME="MediaPlayer" WIDTH="440" HEIGHT="360" autostart="1" showcontrols="1">
</object>
```

The issue that I am encountering, specifically, is that any attempt to set the 'currentPosition' of the 'Controls' member of the 'MediaPlayer' object - yields the following:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'currentPosition' of undefined
```

Per the Object Model Reference, this should work. Per historical accounts, this should work - it has until... very recently. If anyone has any idea why this would stop working 'out of the blue' as it were IN EVERY BROWSER BUT I.E., I'd be very interested in knowing what it is.

I know that this approach is severely deprecated but I do not have the ability to move away from it, as the company I work for has tens of thousands of hours of video in WMV format, even though browser support for WMV is fading quickly.

Started a collaboration at JSFiddle ( Thanks @Bart ).

http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=DvKifcxlR7

Comment: Consider using HTML5 [`<video>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video) instead of relying on plugins.

Comment: If you had read my original post before @Dave Newton decided to remove my commentary, you would note that I have no intention of moving away from this immediately (it's really just not an option), but thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: The error seems to indicate while `MediaPlayer` exists, `MediaPlayer.Controls` does not. Are you sure it's not `MediaPlayer.controls`? In javascript, properties are usually lowercase. Then again, I don't know the API so I could be wrong.

Comment: I've tried most variants uppercase and lowercase; the object model reference claims it's uppercase.

Comment: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564350(v=vs.85).aspx `controls` should be lowercase. What site are you referencing?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd563945(v=vs.85).aspx

...

Like I said though; I have tried both. My actual code is lowercase; I uppercased it to reflect the API for the context of SO - but again... Tried.

Comment: @DigitalJedi805 What I deleted is unrelated to the question. Non-technically related discourse is OT, like the signoff, etc. This is all in the FAQ.

Comment: @DaveNewton - Some of the points you deleted were relevant to my lack of ability to replace this code with HTML5. Feel free to drop the signoff and the variable quotes - but some of that information is pertinent to why I am asking the question.

Comment: @DigitalJedi805 I disagree: you're asking how to solve a specific problem with the code as listed. You are also able to edit your posts to bring them inline with SO guidelines.

Comment: Okay then Dave... Just to satisfy your angst bud, I'll tighten some of it up. You should lighten up though.

Answer (score 1):

What the error is telling you is that while `MediaPlayer` seems to be defined, `MediaPlayer.Controls` is not.

Indeed, according to [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562656(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562656%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) `Player` objects have a `controls` property of type `Controls`. Thus you should write

```
top.mediaFrame.document.MediaPlayer.controls.currentPosition = moviePosition;
top.mediaFrame.document.MediaPlayer.controls.play();
```

Comment: @DigitalJedi805 Are you still getting the same error? jsfiddle.net

Comment: Yes I am, every combination of uppercase or lowercase yields the same result.

Comment: Just ran it all through JSFiddle and got the same result. http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=DvKifcxlR7

Comment: @DigitalJedi805 I just tried it locally and `document.MediaPlayer.controls.currentPosition = moviePosition;` works without errors...

Comment: Can I ask what browser you're in?

Comment: @DigitalJedi805 I've tested it in IE11

Comment: That would be the only browser that it Does work in. See OP :-/

Comment: @DigitalJedi805 Ah, did not notice that. Well, my other browsers do not have WMP plugin and use VLC Media Player plugin instead (which no doubt uses a different API). In fact, it's no longer possible to use WMP in chrome according to http://www.interoperabilitybridges.com/wmp-extension-for-chrome - that may be your problem?

Comment: That's about what I'm concluding myself; I use VLC as well, but it's problematic on computers that aren't as well. My assessment was that we're dead in the water, but I had to try... Thanks for your attempt. You should mod your answer to reflect all of this.

Comment: You could try to detect browsers and use a different `<object>` and javascript code if you need to use VLC. Then again, at that point you should really consider using `<video>` instead.

Comment: Yeah - what we Really need to do is step away from WMV - I've got a flash streaming server and reliable flash player, but the company won't step up for encoding hardware. 400+ days to convert the WMV's we've got to MP4s. ( Video tag won't handle WMV )

Comment: Funny though - not a single upvote. Like I asked a stupid question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's the media player.

Your JavaScript is assuming that the media player is always loaded by the object tag, and is referring to it solely by the id of the object tag.

If the media player is in fact loaded by the embed tag, the JavaScript will not be accessing it.

You need to give an explicit id to the embed tag,  and if the object tag doesn't actually contain a valid media player, you then need to locate the embed tag instead.

Something like:

```
var player = top.mediaFrame.document.getElementById('MediaPlayer);
if (! player || ! player.controls) 
{
    player = top.mediaFrame.document.getElementById('altMediaPlayer')
}
```

Then

```
<embed id = 'altMediaPlayer' TYPE="application/x-mplayer2" SRC="/images/logo.png" NAME="MediaPlayer" WIDTH="440" HEIGHT="360" autostart="1" showcontrols="1">
```

ought to do it.